# Use return value of a block of code as "pure text"

Tags: c, string, return, token, identifier

I don't know if this is the correct terminology, but I'd like to use the return value of a block of code (a token) as "text", here's what I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

typedef struct a{
char *x;
}A;

int main(){

    A name = {"lorem"};

    char a[10]={}, b[10]={};

    scanf("%s %s",&a,&b)

    if (b == a.x){  
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

I altered the actual code completely in order to make it quick and easy.

If the guy writes down "name lorem" in the console, I want the "a" inside the if statement to return "name", which is the identifier of the struct instance previously created, thus making it possible for me to access the member "x" of the struct, and then in this case, the *if* would return true.
If you could suggest anything I'd be grateful : )

Comment: also, change: `scanf("%s %s",&a,&b);` to `scanf("%s %s",a, b);`

Comment: I thought of a better way to formulate the question, it boils down to this: is it possible to compare an identifier to a string?

Comment: @FabrícioSantana No. Identifiers only mean anything to the compiler. Your compiled program doesn't have identifiers in it.